# how much risk is acceptable with damaged classical guitar

Tags: classical-guitar, repair

I saw a cracked Admira Solista guitar on sale at half price online. I am not an expert so I can't tell how badly damaged it is. Is this level of damage acceptable, and is the price reasonable?

[image]

Any help is going to be appreciated.

Comment: [In case it's unrecoverable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqpNQ9AJYgU)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks as though the cracking is in the lacquer only. If that's the case, then it will probably be o.k. However, if the wood itself is cracked, the sound may well be compromised, and will reflect in the fact that the guitar could only be worth 1/3 of its value, as it will need expert repair. The best way to tell is to tap the soundboard to hear if the crack goes through. If it needs physical repair rather than cosmetic,  1/2 price is more than it's worth, unless it's a £500+ instrument, which it's not. It needs to be seen and heard!

Comment: Yeah I only got the part of an internet deal after I answered. Definitely need to try it out before buying.

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on the sound and whether you can live with the imperfections. My first guitar teacher had a very good Yamaha guitar that had a great big chunk of wood in the side missing.

He told me that a music shop he had once worked for had an accident with it and was unable to sell it but when he graduated they thought that maybe he could use a guitar that he can leave at the school and not worry about.

You would never want to give a recital with such a thing though. This on the other hand seems rather minor. That looks just like a rather deep scratch.

As long as the sound of the guitar is still good and you can get a good deal on the instrument that you may on not otherwise be able to afford then I would say go for it.

On the one hand I see instruments purely as tools so I take general good care of them but minor imperfections don't bother me all that much. It may be different for you though so you may have to reflect on what role your instruments is going to take in your life.